# Issue with TCP connection to two ESP8266s

Tags: esp8266

I am working on a project where I want to stream data very quickly (about 300KB/s per ESP8266) to two, or more, ESP8266s over TCP. I have had success with setting up a single ESP8266 in SoftAP mode and connecting to it via my PC directly, and streaming at those speeds or better.

The most obvious solution to connect more than one is to set them up in STA mode and have them connect to a separate commercial Access Point. This works but the data rate drops by about 33%, even for a single ESP8266.

I had the idea of setting up one ESP8266 in SoftAP mode and a second one in STA mode. I was able to connect my PC to the one in SoftAP mode and have the second one connect to it as well without an issue. The problem I ran into is that I could not connect via TCP to the one in STA mode (there was no issue connecting via TCP to the one in SoftAP mode).

ESP8266 in STA ---> ESP8266 in SoftAP <--- PC

My first question is, should this setup be possible, where I would be able to connect to both via TCP (they both have unique IPs)?

Second question is, would it be likely for this setup to speed up the transfer compared to connecting to a commercial Access Point?

Third question is, is it possible that the 33% slow-down, when connecting the ESP8266s to a commercial Access Point, a simple config issue?

Comment: `KB` or `Kb` ? and if "B", please post that amazing code.

Comment: I do mean KB as in Byte. But I did mean 300KB, not 500KB. Updated.  There's no real special code. It's all in C using the SDK, however, instead of LUA or Arduino sketches.